# Debugging a Standalone Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller called 'Zendesk_session_controller.rb', as the first step in a process of using a JWT. However, I would like to know how to debug this with binding.pry? I receive this error when I try to run the file.

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

**zendesk_session_controller.rb**

```
    require 'securerandom' unless defined?(SecureRandom)
class ZendeskSessionController
  # Configuration
  ZENDESK_SHARED_SECRET = ENV['ZENDESK_SHARED_SECRET']
  ZENDESK_SUBDOMAIN     = ENV['ZENDESK_SUBDOMAIN']

  def create
    if user = User.authenticate(params[:login], params[:password])
      # If the submitted credentials pass, then log user into Zendesk
      sign_into_zendesk(user)
    else
      render :new, notice: 'Cannot find user with that username or passowrd.'
    end
  end

  private

  def sign_into_zendesk(user)
    iat = Time.now.to_i
    jti = "#{iat}/#{SecureRandom.hex(18)}"

    payload = JWT.encode({
                           iat: iat, # Seconds since epoch, determine when this token is stale
                           jti: jti, # Unique token id, helps prevent replay attacks
                           name: user.name,
                           email: user.email
                         }, ZENDESK_SHARED_SECRET)

    redirect_to zendesk_sso_url(payload)
  end

  def zendesk_sso_url(payload)
    url = "https://#{ZENDESK_SUBDOMAIN}.zendesk.com/access/jwt?jwt=#{payload}"
    url += '&' + { return_to: params['return_to'] }.to_query if params['return_to'].present?
    url
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

Comment: It is pretty complex I'm afraid - controllers are pretty closely coupled with many objects: routes, request, response, view etc. `request` comes from the `rack` stack, so it is not an easily recreatable object. Easiest approach is to simply run a local server which will trigger pry. More correct way is to move whole business logc out of the controller into a well defined service object that can be tested in isolation.

Comment: @BroiSatse its actually not that complicated - its just a bad idea. You create a [Rack::MockedRequest](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/MockRequest) and pass it to an instance of your controller. Rails controllers are Rack middleware so the interface is pretty straight forward,. Its how the deprechiated ActionController::TestCase works. Moving the logic out of the controller as yu recommended is a way better idea though.

Comment: Ah, true! Completely forgot about MockRequest! (That's actually a good thing - means no legacy code work for me lately :)) Thanks for reminding

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `binding.pry` before `redirect_to`

```rb
  def sign_into_zendesk(user)
    iat = Time.now.to_i
    jti = "#{iat}/#{SecureRandom.hex(18)}"

    payload = JWT.encode({
                           iat: iat, # Seconds since epoch, determine when this token is stale
                           jti: jti, # Unique token id, helps prevent replay attacks
                           name: user.name,
                           email: user.email
                         }, ZENDESK_SHARED_SECRET)

    binding.pry

    redirect_to zendesk_sso_url(payload)
  end
```